Need to extract embedded files from word document, where pdf, word, xslx , zip are available in the file
I extracted the embedded files using lxml docx to xml content and check for word/embeddings. I can able to extract the docx, xslx files as it is saved in the same format in the xml. But for pdf and zip files it is extracted as .bin format from the embeddings. I tried and extracted the pdf files from the .bin format files and saved. But i cannot able to perform the same for the zip file. Currently inside my zip file has a image file(tif) but it can be anything pdf or something i need to extract that in a .zip foramt and save the same.
def extract_embedded_files_from_docx(self,docx_file):
    """
    Extracts embedded files from a DOCX file.
    """
    embedded_files = {}

    azure_func = Azure()

    blob_data = azure_func.read_file(
        file_path=docx_file, is_text_content=False
    )
    
    # Open the DOCX file (which is a ZIP archive)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(blob_data), 'r') as docx_zip:
        # Iterate through files in the DOCX zip to find embedded files
        for file in docx_zip.namelist():
            if file.startswith('word/embeddings/'):
                file_name = os.path.basename(file)
                bin_file_data = docx_zip.read(file)
                # Check if the file is an oleObject*.bin (which could be PDFs or other file types)
                if file_name.startswith('oleObject') and file_name.endswith('.bin'):
                    # Use python-magic to detect the file type

                    mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
                    file_type = mime.from_buffer(bin_file_data)

                    if file_type == 'application/CDFV2':
                        # Open the CDFV2 (OLE) file using olefile
                        ole = olefile.OleFileIO(BytesIO(bin_file_data))

                        embedded_file_name = self.extract_file_name_from_ole(ole)
                        
                        # List the available storages/streams in the CDFV2 file
                        storages = ole.listdir()
                        print("Storages in CDFV2 file:", storages)
                        
                        # Extract from the 'CONTENTS' stream
                        if ['CONTENTS'] in storages:
                                # Extract the file content from the 'CONTENTS' stream
                                file_data = ole.openstream(['CONTENTS']).read()
                                print(f"Extracted content from 'CONTENTS' stream.")
                        else:
                            # Try extracting data from '\x01Ole' or '\x01Ole10Native'
                            file_data = None
                            for storage in storages:
                                if storage in [['\x01Ole'], ['\x01Ole10Native']]:
                                    print(f"Found embedded file in {storage}. Extracting data...")
                                    file_data = ole.openstream(storage).read()
                                    break
                                # Use magic to check file type (e.g., PDF, Excel, etc.)
                        embedded_file_type = magic.Magic(mime=True).from_buffer(file_data)

                        if embedded_file_type == 'application/octet-stream':
                            if len(storages) <= 4:
                                image_file_name = file_name.replace('.bin', ".tif")
                                with open(f"image.tif", 'wb') as image_file:
                                    image_file.write(bin_file_data)
                                zip_file_name = file_name.replace('.bin', '.zip')
                                with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w') as zipf:
                                    zipf.write(image_file_name, os.path.basename(image_file_name))
                                file_name=image_file_name.replace('.bin', '.zip')
                                # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.zip'))

                        # Determine the correct extension based on MIME type
                        if embedded_file_type == 'application/pdf':
                            file_name=file_name.replace('.bin', '.pdf')
                            # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.pdf'))
                        elif embedded_file_type == 'application/zip':
                            file_name=file_name.replace('.bin', '.zip')
                            # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.zip'))
                        elif embedded_file_type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
                            file_name=file_name.replace('.bin', '.xlsx')
                            # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.xlsx'))
                        elif embedded_file_type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
                            file_name=file_name.replace('.bin', '.xlsx')
                            # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.xlsx'))
                        elif embedded_file_type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
                            file_name=file_name.replace('.bin', '.docx')
                            # self.save_file_with_extension(file_data, file_name.replace('.bin', '.docx'))
                    else:
                        # If the type is unknown, keep the file name as it is, with .bin extension
                        file_name = file_name.replace('.bin', '.bin')
                    try:
                        embedded_files[file_name] = file_data
                    except:
                        embedded_files[file_name] = bin_file_data

                else:
                    embedded_files[file_name] = bin_file_data
                    
    return embedded_files

basically the bin file content type is CDFV2 from that i extract and the contents and then check for content type it has been giving me pdf but for zip it gives as application/octet-stream but if i save it in zip or save it in tif and convert to zip also i didn't able to view the file. Please help me to fix this issue.
